# PHP from loop to JSON formatting won't match

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this array

```
$data = [ 'admin'=>'1', 'natasha'=>'2', 'demo3'=>'3' ];
```

When I output it `echo json_encode($data);` I get `{"admin":"1","natasha":"2","demo3":"3"}` and this how I need it and it works well!

Now I'm trying to loop data from database like this:

```
    $data = array();
    foreach(TopicModel::theListofUsers($topic_cat,30) as $row) {                
       $data[]= array($row->user_name=>$row->user_id);  
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
```

But I'm getting this format `[{"demo4":"4"},{"demo3":"3"}]` but I need **`{"admin":"1","natasha":"2","demo3":"3"}`**

I tried many things, pass strings and convert to array or manipulate array but none of it gave me the proper format. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data = array();
foreach(TopicModel::theListofUsers($topic_cat,30) as $row) {                
   $data[$row->user_name] = $row->user_id;
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you want, you need to set the name as the array key inside your foreach loop:

```
$data = array();
foreach(TopicModel::theListofUsers($topic_cat,30) as $row)
{                
   $data[$row->user_name]= $row->user_id;  
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

And I suggest that you escape both key and value of your array to avoid unwanted characters, otherwise your json_encode will fail returning false.

A simply way to do it can be: `str_replace("'", "", $row->user_name)` and `str_replace("'", "", $row->user_id)`.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think `user_name` or `user_id` will ever have quotes in it

Comment: Yes, I don't think so too. But this is a good coding practice, you will avoid PHP errors with it. It is defensive programming. Unless you are sure that these data is already treated.

Comment: so you think in coding is good to do extra things even though are not necessary? I tested it and the system won't let me add `'` for usernames